# Insert range based on activecell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

At the moment I have a code that copies a range from a different sheet in the same workbook to the sheet where I activated the macro.

This is where I need help:

I would like the macro to run only when the activecell is in column C **and** has a certain value. This value can be found in a list in range `A1:A10`

The part where the activecell must be in column C, I have managed. Now the other part. This is the code I have until now.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ActiveCell.Column <> 3 Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell in column C", vbExclamation

Else
    With Sheets("Info").Range("A25:J27").Copy 
        Sheets("Main").Activate
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    End With
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'puts value in cell to trigger change event macro
Range("A1").Value = 1`
```

For example, my list contains the words car, house, dog. So when my activecell is in Column C and has one of these three values in it and I click on the CommandButton, I want the macro to run. If the activecell is not in column C or not one of these three values a MsgBox appears.

I would really appreciate help with this last part, because I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of a function i.e. Contains maybe:

```
If ActiveCell.Column = 3 And Contains(ActiveCell.Value, [d1:d3]) Then
'your code
End If


    Public Function Contains(val, searchrange As Range)
    Dim item As Range
    For Each item In searchrange
    If val = item.Value Then Contains = True: Exit Function
    Next
    Contains = False
    End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for the late respons, I didn't have the excel workbook at my disposal this weekend. I have tried your code and it works great, thank you. Is it also possible to to change the search range to another worksheet? Example: [D1:D3] to lets say: worksheet("sheet1").range("D1:D3")

Comment: How do I manage this? Because worksheet("sheet1").range("D1:D3") gives me an error

Comment: Try ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")